# Dart Js-Interop function type parameters

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

As a follow-up to my question [Dart JS Library, how to pass callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965165/dart-js-library-how-to-pass-callback-functions/39007989#39007989), I want to ensure that any functions passed through to D3 have the right parameters.

So I would like to do something like the following:

```
@JS('d3')
library d3;

import 'dart:js';
import "package:js/js.dart";

typedef num D3AccessorFunction(List<num> d, num i, List<List<num>> data);


@JS('line')
class Line {
  external Line();
  external String call (List<List<num>> data);
  external Line x(D3AccessorFunction func);
  external Line y(num func(List<num> d, num i, List<List<num>> data));
}
```

Then when I call the method:

```
Line line = new Line();
line.x(
    allowInterop(
        (List<num> d, num i, List<List<num>> data) {
            return d[0]+10;
        }
    )
);
```

I would like it to complain if the parameters aren't matched properly, e.g.,

```
line.x(
    allowInterop(
        (List<num> d) {
            return d[0]+10;
        }
    )
);
```

Unfortunately, the allowInterop swallows this complaint and you can't get rid of it. 
I've created a work-around (in the d3 definition):

```
Function d3Function(D3AccessorFunction function) {
    return allowInterop(function);
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
line.x(
    d3Function(
        (List<num> d, num i, List<List<num>> data) {
            return d[0]+10;
        }
    )
);
```

Which will throw the right errors. But I'd like to know if there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We no longer need to define our own JavaScript definition files, as Dart has a tool for doing so from TypeScript files. The [JS Facade Generator](https://github.com/dart-lang/js_facade_gen).
There's more information on using this on the [official Dart Page about JS Interoperability](https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/web-programming#js-interop).

Thanks to the [DefinitelyTyped project](http://definitelytyped.org/), there's almost certainly a TypeScript file out there that will allow you to do this. If not, write one of those instead, it'll help both the Dart and TypeScript communities.